# Get only the first level of child categories

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list, category-products

I would like to list **only** the first level child categories of the current category.

This is what is have right now:

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();    
$_categories = $_category
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description'))
                ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());

foreach ($_categories as $_category):
   echo $_category->getName();
endforeach;
```

The shop is using flat categories, and i have no idea how to show **only** the first level of child categories.

Been searching a lot but every script i use still show all the sub-sub categories instead only the sub categories.

EDIT:

Just to be clear

When the current page is:

```
Category (current page)

-- sub A <-- show this sub category
--- sub A sub
---- sub A sub sub

-- sub B <-- show this sub category
--- sub B sub
---- sub B sub sub

Category 

-- sub A (current page) 
--- sub A sub <-- show this sub category
---- sub A sub sub

-- sub B
--- sub B sub
---- sub B sub sub
```

Comment: first level means immediate children categories?

Comment: Hi @AmitBera Yes this is right. I updated the initial question, please have a look

Comment: $_category = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();  should be $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

Answer (score 3):

use below code to get first level category

```
  $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addIsActiveFilter()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level','1');


    foreach($categories as $item)
    {
        echo $item->getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting all  immediate child categories try this

### For getting get immediate active categories:

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');    
$_categories = $_category->getChildrenCategories()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description'))
                ;

foreach ($_categories as $_category):
   echo $_category->getName().'<br/>';
endforeach;
```

### With Including inactive Children categories:

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');    
$_categories = $_category->getChildrenCategoriesWithInactive($_category)
                ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'description'))
                ;

foreach ($_categories as $_category):
   echo $_category->getName().'<br/>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: when i do this i get a empty page (without sidebar etc.) When i var_dump $_category it give me stuff back but when i var_dump($_categories); die(); it shows nothing.

Comment: on which pages,are you trying this?

Comment: for now on the catalog/category/view.phtml and will put it in a extension later

Comment: then it should works...

Comment: $_categories did not provide the data.you cam get data when use foreach loop

Comment: The above code doesn't show anything. Strange thing is: Category A on level 1 it shows only level 2 but on level 2 it shows 3,4,5 etc. Category B on level 2 it shows level 2,3,4 etc. Category C on level 1 it shows only level 2 on level 2 it shows 3,4,5.... strange...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get the first level child categories of the given category.
`$_categories = $category->getResource()->getChildren($category,false);`
Where `false` in the argument is for recursive, so if you want the recursive categories, you can replace the `false` with `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
$cat_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
$sub_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($cat_id);
```

or you can also filter the category collection by parent id

```
$cat_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
$sub_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter("parent_id",$cat_id);
```

For me i prefer first method 
hope this will help you